# In MFC how do I avoid dialog boxes from staying on top of my app window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, mfc

I have a dialog box based application (MFC - VS 2008).  I have a list control on it.  I pop up other dialog boxes, but I also want to be able to get back to the parent app dialog.  I can get back to the parent app dilaog box, but the problem is that even if I click on it with the mouse it remains hidden behind the "child" windows.

I want it to come to the front.

There is probably something obvious I am doing wrong.  What do I need to do to make the parent window come to the front when it has focus?  I assume there is some property on the child dlg that should not be there, or something missing

I can post the rc code if that helps.

EDIT:

here is the .rc code for the two dialog boxes.  The first is the mainframe window.

The second is launched with the following code:

```
HistogramWindow *histwind;

histwind = new  HistogramWindow(this);  
histwind->Create(IDD_DIALOG_HISTOGRAM);
histwind->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

IDD_DTHISTOGRAMDLG_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 200
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "dtHistogramDlg"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,209,179,50,14,NOT WS_VISIBLE
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,263,179,50,14,NOT WS_VISIBLE
    CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST_SYMBOL_SETS,"SysListView32",LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,7,7,60,50
END

IDD_DIALOG_HISTOGRAM DIALOGEX 0, 0, 317, 184
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "Histogram"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,205,163,50,14,NOT WS_VISIBLE
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,260,163,50,14,NOT WS_VISIBLE
    CONTROL         "",IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_BLACKFRAME,7,7,20,20
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine suggested the following (and it work)

- set the style of the 2nd dlg to WS_CHILD
- histwind->SetParent( NULL );
- histwind->ModifyStyle( WS_CHILD, 0 );

This works, however thereis a strange behavior when i move the parent window from behind a child.  While moving the window is hidden until I release the mouse.

This will work for now.

thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using a modal dialog box via calling `DoModal`.
Instead, you need to create a [modeless dialog box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w2h2y4y(VS.80).aspx).

To do this, use [CWnd::Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yhc9kx4(VS.80).aspx) and [CWnd::ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72szh9c7(VS.80).aspx).

**Example:**

```
CMyDialog *m_pMyDialog = new CMyDialog(this);
m_pMyDialog->Create(CMyDialog::IDD);
m_pMyDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: I was already doing that.  The problem is not that I can't get to the mainframe parent window - I can, it is just that the child windows always are in front - even if the mainframe has focus.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW` for the second dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the second Dialog was running inside a CWinThread.

My Solution was:

m_pDlg->Create(IDD_DIALOG, CWnd::FromHandle(GetDesktopWindow()));

I Found further help hrer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1651/Tutorial-Modeless-Dialogs-with-MFC

Comment: Your answer is dangerously close to being a link-only answer. Please summarize the main contents of the link in your answer, so that search engines can index it better and there'll still be useful information if the link goes dead.

Comment: I've no CWinThread, but this answer worked for me when none of the above did. Thanks! (although I didn't need to add the extra CWnd::FromHandle call.)